# Using Node js, how to get weather feeds for multiple cities in single request using yahoo weather api

Tags: javascript, node.js, yahoo, yahoo-weather-api

I'm using yahoo weather api for get weather feed of single city, now I want to get weather feed for multiple cities in single request, how can I do using yahoo api. I also want to know, is ther any api yahoo provides to get the list of city of any country.

My weather.js

```
 import OAuth from 'oauth';

    const header = {
      "X-Yahoo-App-Id": "myappid"
    };

   const request = new OAuth.OAuth(
         null,
         null,
         'myconsumerkey',
         'myconsumersecret',
         '1.0',
         null,
         'HMAC-SHA1',
         null,
         header
        );

request.get('https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss?w=713169&format=json', null,null, function (err, data, result) {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
       } else {
         console.log(data)
       }
     });
```

Using this code i can be able to get weather details for only one city i want to fetch weather details for multiple cities at once.

thanx in advance!!

Comment: Hey, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hey @razki, what you feels wrong in my question asking technique, can u tell me.

Comment: You’ve provided no code for us to help with.

Comment: thank you very  much @razki, i have added code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So reading the documentation it doesn't seem possible to send a batch of locations to the Yahoo Weather API. But what you can do is `.map()` over an array of locations and make multiple requests.

https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/documentation.html#params

Since OAuth 1.0 is a callback, I've wrapped that with a `new Promise()`, which will give us an array of unfulfilled promises. Then finally, `Promise.all()` method returns a single Promise that fulfills when all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled.

```
const OAuth = require('oauth')

const header = {
    'X-Yahoo-App-Id': 'your-app-id',
}

const request = new OAuth.OAuth(null, null, 'your-consumer-key', 'your-consumer-secret', '1.0', null, 'HMAC-SHA1', null, header)

const locations = ['pittsburgh,pa', 'london']

const getWeatherData = () =>
    Promise.all(
        locations.map(
            location =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                    request.get(`https://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss?location=${location}&format=json`, null, null, (err, data) => {
                        if (err) return reject(err)
                        return resolve(data)
                    })
                )
        )
    )

const main = async () => {
    const test = await getWeatherData()

    console.log(test)
}

main()
```

I have tested this with the API and here is an example response for the code above.

```
[
    '{"location":{"city":"Pittsburgh","region":" PA","woeid":2473224,"country":"United States","lat":40.431301,"long":-79.980698,"timezone_id":"America/New_York"},"current_observation":{"wind":{"chill":32,"direction":280,"speed":5.59},"atmosphere":{"humidity":70,"visibility":10.0,"pressure":29.03,"rising":0},"astronomy":{"sunrise":"6:42 am","sunset":"7:59 pm"},"condition":{"text":"Partly Cloudy","code":30,"temperature":37},"pubDate":1586862000},"forecasts":[{"day":"Tue","date":1586836800,"low":38,"high":45,"text":"Mostly Cloudy","code":28},{"day":"Wed","date":1586923200,"low":32,"high":47,"text":"Partly Cloudy","code":30},{"day":"Thu","date":1587009600,"low":31,"high":45,"text":"Partly Cloudy","code":30},{"day":"Fri","date":1587096000,"low":35,"high":42,"text":"Rain And Snow","code":5},{"day":"Sat","date":1587182400,"low":35,"high":51,"text":"Scattered Showers","code":39},{"day":"Sun","date":1587268800,"low":42,"high":59,"text":"Rain","code":12},{"day":"Mon","date":1587355200,"low":43,"high":55,"text":"Mostly Cloudy","code":28},{"day":"Tue","date":1587441600,"low":37,"high":58,"text":"Partly Cloudy","code":30},{"day":"Wed","date":1587528000,"low":44,"high":61,"text":"Partly Cloudy","code":30},{"day":"Thu","date":1587614400,"low":50,"high":59,"text":"Mostly Cloudy","code":28}]}',
    '{"location":{"city":"London","region":" England","woeid":44418,"country":"United Kingdom","lat":51.506401,"long":-0.12721,"timezone_id":"Europe/London"},"current_observation":{"wind":{"chill":46,"direction":70,"speed":6.84},"atmosphere":{"humidity":50,"visibility":10.0,"pressure":30.27,"rising":0},"astronomy":{"sunrise":"6:04 am","sunset":"7:58 pm"},"condition":{"text":"Mostly Sunny","code":34,"temperature":49},"pubDate":1586862000},"forecasts":[{"day":"Tue","date":1586818800,"low":38,"high":54,"text":"Partly Cloudy","code":30},{"day":"Wed","date":1586905200,"low":34,"high":62,"text":"Mostly Sunny","code":34},{"day":"Thu","date":1586991600,"low":38,"high":68,"text":"Partly Cloudy","code":30},{"day":"Fri","date":1587078000,"low":45,"high":62,"text":"Rain","code":12},{"day":"Sat","date":1587164400,"low":45,"high":60,"text":"Rain","code":12},{"day":"Sun","date":1587250800,"low":42,"high":63,"text":"Partly Cloudy","code":30},{"day":"Mon","date":1587337200,"low":44,"high":64,"text":"Scattered Showers","code":39},{"day":"Tue","date":1587423600,"low":44,"high":66,"text":"Partly Cloudy","code":30},{"day":"Wed","date":1587510000,"low":45,"high":67,"text":"Mostly Cloudy","code":28},{"day":"Thu","date":1587596400,"low":44,"high":65,"text":"Mostly Cloudy","code":28}]}',
]
```